# SqlDatasource select parameters

Tags: gridview, sqldatasource, sqlparameter

Here is my sql datasource details

```
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsMoodleQuiz" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OnlineMeetingConnectionString %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OnlineMeetingConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 

    SelectCommand="SELECT Name, UserID, Grade, FirstName, LastName, Email, TimeModified, IDNumber FROM tbMoodleQuiz WHERE (FirstName = @FirstName) AND (LastName = @LastName)" 
    onselecting="dsMoodleQuiz_Selecting">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

A gridview by name gvDetails is attached to dsMoodleQuiz . On `button click` I would like

gridview to get populated.

Here is the code on button click

```
 protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    dsMoodleQuiz.SelectParameters.Add("@FirstName", System.Data.DbType.String, "Jhon");
    dsMoodleQuiz.SelectParameters.Add("@LastName", System.Data.DbType.String, "Wald");

    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Why is this not working ...?? Am I missing any code ...?? Appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sample example on how to search grid view and populating results on that search criteria using sqldatasource.....

grid view binding .....

```
     <asp:GridView ID="Gridview1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True"
AllowSorting="true" DataSourceID="dsGridview" Width="540px" PageSize="10">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="id" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="FirstName">
        <ItemStyle Width="120px" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblFirstname" Text='<%# HighlightText(Eval("FirstName")) %>' 
                runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="LastName">
        <ItemStyle Width="120px" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblLastname" Text='<%# HighlightText(Eval("LastName")) %>' 
            runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Department" HeaderText="Department" 
        SortExpression="Department" ItemStyle-Width="130px" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Location" HeaderText="Location" 
        SortExpression="Location" ItemStyle-Width="130px" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and sql datasource is like this ...

```
   <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM People"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
    FilterExpression="firstname like '%{0}%' or lastname like '%{1}%'">
    <FilterParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="firstname" ControlID="txtSearch" PropertyName="Text" />
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="lastname" ControlID="txtSearch" PropertyName="Text" />
    </FilterParameters>
  </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

adding text box for searching ..

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" />
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnSearch" ImageUrl="images/searchbutton.png" runat="server" />
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnClear" ImageUrl="images/clearbutton.png" runat="server" />
```

and this is code for binding and entering  text into text box

```
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
Partial;
class GridviewwithHighlightedSearch : System.Web.UI.Page {

    //  Create a String to store our search results
    private string SearchString = "";

    string HighlightText(string InputTxt) {
        //  This function is called whenever text is displayed in the FirstName and LastName 
        //  fields from our database. If we're not searching then just return the original 
        //  input, this speeds things up a bit
        if ((SearchString == "")) {
            return InputTxt;
        }
        else {
            //  Otherwise create a new regular expression and evaluate the FirstName and 
            //  LastName fields against our search string.
            Regex ResultStr;
            ResultStr = new Regex(SearchString.Replace(" ", "|"), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            return ResultStr.Replace(InputTxt, new MatchEvaluator(new System.EventHandler(this.ReplaceWords)));
        }
    }

    public string ReplaceWords(Match m) {
        //  This match evaluator returns the found string and adds it a CSS class I defined 
        //  as 'highlight'
        return ("<span class=highlight>" 
                    + (m.ToString + "</span>"));
    }

    protected void btnClear_Click(object sender, System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs e) {
        //  Simple clean up text to return the Gridview to it's default state
        txtSearch.Text = "";
        SearchString = "";
        Gridview1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs e) {
        //  Set the value of the SearchString so it gets 
        SearchString = txtSearch.Text;
    }
}
```

and this is the css style for hilighting..

and this is teh image for the above grid view

[image]

```
    <style type="text/css">
   .highlight {text-decoration: none;color:black;background:yellow;}
</style>
```

i hope it will helps you...

Comment: How/where is the SQLDatasource getting populated with new search data which intern gets attached to gridview ...???

Comment: <FilterParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="firstname" ControlID="txtSearch" PropertyName="Text" />
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="lastname" ControlID="txtSearch" PropertyName="Text" />
    </FilterParameters>
see this line and you can use filter expression also

Answer (score 0):

Using the following code in databaindg

```
dsMoodleQuiz.SelectParmeter['FirstName'].DefaultValue = 'John';
dsMoodleQuiz.SelectParmeter['LastName'].DefaultValue = 'Wald';

gridView1.DataBind();
```

Note: I dont have visual studio with me, so the code is not copy, pastable.