# How to change a Label text upon another DropdownList SelectIndexChange event, but they share a same SQLDataSource

Tags: asp.net, controls, html-select

I have an **SQLDataSource** consisted of 3 columns:

1. A - a value, numeric
2. B - a name, text
3. C - a comment, large text

Also there is a DropdownList control with its

```
DataValueField of A column - to be stored in the database after form submission
DataTextField of B column - display purpose for the DropdownList Control
```

Now what I want to do is:
 upon the selection change of this DropdownList control, I want to change another Label's text into its corresponding

```
C column - so that the more detailed comments or explanations will be given upon user's selection of the item
```

How do I do this?

---

Thank you @Nate for the edits :)

Comment: do you have any use of datavaluefied of A column of drownlist

Comment: @krshekhar Yes, the DataValueField(A) is used for actual program's interaction with the database. Column B is for the display purpose of the DropdownList control. And Column C in the Label control is for extra Comment for that selected item.

Comment: I thin you should look for some kind of filter on your sqldatasource on the basis of dropdown selected value. Do you knwo how to filter the values from sqldatasource

Comment: @krshekhar no sir. What is it?

Comment: there is no perfect example but you can go through this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880175/sqldatasource-select-parameters